# How to write a file on the internal storage next to the download folder?

Tags: android

I was not able to write a file to the internal storage of my nexus 10, that sits next to folders like "Downloads", "Movies", "Music" and "Pictures", so directly inside the root.

I would like to create an own folder for my application in that root directory and store log files inside. How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath().toString() }, null, null);
```

This code updates the file tree on the usb device and makes the correctly created files visible.